# OnSave event fires twice when calling preventDefault after clicking Save and Close button

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I've got the following `onSave` handler on my form:

```
onSave: function (executionContext) {
    var eventArgs = executionContext.getEventArgs();
    var isValid = validate();
    if (!isValid) {
        eventArgs.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
},
```

To my surprise, `onSave` is called twice if `preventDefault()` is called, but only when clicking the "Save and Close" button (this behavior doesn't happen when clicking the "Save" button).

Note that you can use the following code as well to reproduce the issue:

```
onSave: function (executionContext) {
    var eventArgs = executionContext.getEventArgs();
    eventArgs.preventDefault();
},
```

I'd like to know if that's a known issue, and if so, what's your approach to solve it?

Comment: If you share your `HTML` code also, it will be helpful to us to tell what is going wrong

Comment: @Javascript_Lover, this is a question about a built-in event in MS Dynamics CRM. HTML is irrelevant here.

Comment: Are you passing your executionContext? Make sure you check the "Pass execution context as first parameter" while adding your function to onSave event handlers.

Comment: @jasonscript, yes, it's passed.

Comment: @HeyJude did you end up solving this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have auto-save turned on (System Setting - Enable auto-save on all forms). For auto-save, save is done when you click save and also when you close/navigate from the form. So this is basically by design- one event is triggered because you clicked the "Save" and second is because you also are closing the form (which basically is what "Save and Close" does).

You can check if this is auto-save using something like:

```
var eventArgs = econtext.getEventArgs();
if (eventArgs.getSaveMode() == 70 || eventArgs.getSaveMode() == 2) {
   //here you know you are in auto-save
}
```

Comment: @Pawel Gradecki, unfortunately, that's not the case: Auto-Save is disabled, and `getSaveMode()` returns `2` on both executions of `onSave`.